# Server startup error - Error in SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I used mysql server 5.6.19 and mysql-connector-Java-5.0.8. I have following error.

```
ERROR {xxxxxxx} -  Error while retrieving roles from Internal JDBC role store
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;             
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use                         
near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=100' at line 1
```

Is this mysql server compatibility error ??

Is anyone can find what is the reason for this?

Comment: 'cos this is not valid MySQL SQL

Comment: as docs `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15`

Comment: @ScaryWombat It used to be valid, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that - probably - the JDBC driver is using the old `SET OPTION <option-name> ...` syntax, that has been deprecated since MySQL 5.0 (maybe earlier). See the comment on [`SET` in the MySQL 5.0 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-statement.html):

> Older versions of MySQL employed `SET OPTION`, but this syntax is deprecated in favor of `SET` without `OPTION`.

MySQL 5.6 only supports [`SET <option-name> ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-statement.html).

Your JDBC driver is really old. See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66659 : you need to upgrade the Connector/J library to a - vastly - newer version (eg the latest: 5.1.32: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ ).

This is assuming that your code doesn't execute any `SET OPTION ...` commands itself. Otherwise you will need to fix your code to use the newer syntax.